# How to set variable by just mentioning the number on command line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script

I want to make a script where I can mention the matchid in argument and then it selects to value of variable like below

```
1=IND vs PAK
2=SA vs SL
3=AUS vs ENG
```

So like when I run the script as

```
./match.sh --matchid 2
```

It gives output as

```
SA vs SL
```

**Edit:
what if instead of output I have to assign it to a variable?**

Comment: Have you tried to use $1 to get the second parameter from the command line? Do you have an example script?

Comment: @CJMendes I am very new to bash scripting. I also don't know what to search on google to find such type of feature. Can you please post a sample script for above example

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to refer to a variable by its name stored in another variable. Here's [a question I've found on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16553089/1937994).

In a nutshell:

```bash
$ FOO='value of foo'
$ BAR='value of bar'
$ NAME=FOO
$ echo ${!NAME}
value of foo
```

Answer (score 0):

A small example of catching command line parameters that you can build from:

```bash
#!/bin/bash 
firstparam=$1 
secondparam=$2 
if [[ $firstparam = "--matchid" ]]; then 
   echo -e "You selected to match the id\r" 
fi 
 
case $secondparam in 
    1) echo -e "Samson VS Goliath\r" 
    ;; 
    2) echo -e "Peanuts VS GArfield\r" 
    ;; 
esac
```

Just use in the prompt like: `yourscript.sh --matchid 1`

Comment: what if instead of output I have to assign it to a variable?